# Condition based file installtion in x64 and x86 machines

Tags: windows, build, installation, wix, windows-installer

Hi how can I update my installer script condition to install the following files on 
x86 and x64 machines.

```
<Component Id="Comp.Comp1" Guid="*" >
  <Condition><![CDATA[VersionNT < 602]]></Condition>
  <File Id="File1" Source="$(Dir1)\TestFile.dll" />
 </Component>

<Component Id="Comp.Comp2" Guid="*" >
  <Condition><![CDATA[VersionNT >= 602]]></Condition>
  <File Id="File2" Source="$(Dir2)\TestFile.dll" />
</Component>
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That code will install files just fine on x86 an x64 machines. Note that the Windows Installer requires a 64-bit package to be built to install to 64-bit locations. 32-bit packages only install to 32-bit locations. Unfortunately, 64-bit packages cannot install on 32-bit machines.

The end result is that you need two packages to natively install on 32-bit and 64-bit machines.

Comment: So what is the need for VersionNT and VersionNT64.

Comment: VersionNT64 is **only** set on 64-bit. VersionNT is always set, both 32-bit and 64-bit.

Comment: Thankyou very much for your valuable comments Rob